# Load csv and show progress bar or spinner

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am trying to show a progress bar or something similar just to keep the user busy while the data from the csv to mysql table using php. Below is the code that is called when pressing the import button:

```
if(isset($_POST['importSubmit'])){
    //validate whether uploaded file is a csv file
    $csvMimes = array('application/vnd.ms-excel','text/plain','text/csv','text/tsv');
    if(!empty($_FILES['file']['name']) && in_array($_FILES['file']['type'],$csvMimes)){
        if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){
            //open uploaded csv file with read only mode
            $csvFile = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'r');
            //skip first line
            fgetcsv($csvFile);
            //parse data from csv file line by line
            while(($line = fgetcsv($csvFile)) !== FALSE){
                //insert member data into database
                $db->query("INSERT INTO members (name, email) VALUES ('".$line[0]."','".$line[1]."')");
            }
            //close opened csv file
            fclose($csvFile);
            echo $status_s;
        }else{
            echo $status_e;
        }
    }else{
        echo $status_f;
    }
}
```

Comment: there is a much much better way http://stackoverflow.com/a/2369500/267540

Comment: How big is the csv-file?

Comment: It contains 2000 records at the moment. It varies from time to time

Comment: Records are usually more than 2500